# When can we integrate probability measures?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Say I have a probability space $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mu)$, some real-valued random variables $X_1, X_2$ over this space, and some interval $I \in \mathbb{R}$. Under what conditions on the probability space of the random variables is it the case that:

\begin{align*}
\mu(\omega | X_1(\omega) \in I_1) = \int_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \mu(\omega | X_1(\omega) \in I_1, X_2(\omega) = x) dx
\end{align*}

Comment: sorry, I dont know this notation, what means $X(\omega)\in dx$? It is the same that integrating respect to $x$ with the condition $X(\omega)=x$, maybe?

Comment: yes, that's right. I have edited the notation to make this more clear.

Comment: I suspect that this new notation is not correct either because if $X_2$ is continuous then the integral in the RHS is zero. Where is this exercise from? It is from some textbook?

Comment: @Masacroso RHS is $0$ even if $X_2$ is not continuous. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right side is **always** $0$. This is becasue $\mu(X_2=x)$ is $0$ for all but countably many values of $x$ and countable sets have Lebesgue measure $0$.